# In Forth, what happens if I call DOES> twice?

Tags: forth

John Hayes' ANS Forth test suite contains tests that look like this:

```
: WEIRD: CREATE DOES> 1 + DOES> 2 + ; 
WEIRD: W1
W1
```

I'm rather at a loss as to exactly what this is supposed to do. The [ANS Forth Specification](http://lars.nocrew.org/dpans/dpans6.htm#6.1.1250) on `DOES>` is largely impenetrable.

From reading the test suite, it looks like it's expecting the first call to `DOES>` to modify `W1`, but then that calling `W1` activates the *second* `DOES>`. I assume the second one operates on the word defined by the most recent call to `CREATE`, but that's already been `DOES>`ified, so I'm not sure what that's supposed to do.

gforth passes the test suite, so the tests do seem to be valid; but my pet Forth interpreter doesn't, and I need to figure out how to make it work...

Comment: It's been a while (30+ years) since I dabbled in Forth, but perhaps [this](http://www.vintagecomputer.net/fjkraan/comp/atom/doc/ForthTheory&Practice_10-index.pdf) will help.

Comment: Re "DOES>": Chapter 11, "Creating Defining Words", p. 229-246, in *[Forth - A Text and Reference](http://www.amazon.com/Forth-Reference-Prentice-Hall-Software-Series/dp/0133263312)* by Mahlon G. Kelly and Nicholas Spies (ISBN 0133263312/978-0133263312), may be of use. The central page is page 234. [It may be available on Google Books](https://books.google.dk/books?hl=da&id=AIVGAAAAYAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=various+defining+words) (but I could only see the first few lines) - a feasible way is to borrow it from a library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second call to `DOES>` also modifies `W1`.

`WEIRD:` creates `W1` with a runtime action of `1 + DOES> 2 +`.  The first call to `W1` sets the runtime to `2 +`.

This is more apparent if you change the code to print something, e.g.

```
: weird:   create  does> drop ." ONE"  does> drop ." TWO" ; ok
weird: w1 ok
w1 ONE ok
w1 TWO ok
w1 TWO ok
w1 TWO ok
```

The explanation for this is that `DOES>` always operates on the latest defined word.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. Of course, given that my implementation of `DOES>` works by defining a new word which calls the old one, this is actually kind of hard to implement. I'm seriously considering just abandoning this part of the ANS standard. Apparently a lot of it is considered pretty weird anyway..

Comment: "Calling the old word" is a weird way to go about it. The "old word" is meant to be used to *define* stuff, the "new word" defined by "calling the old word" runs what comes after the `DOES>`

Comment: The requirement that the behaviour of a created word is changed later, is also detrimental to implementation where code is in flash, for no good reason IMO.